# Check if a value is NULL on a query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an attendence log, where I am using:

```
$sql="SELECT date FROM daily_entry_log_2011 WHERE logout_time > '16:30:00' AND  
logout_time < '18:30:00' AND date BETWEEN '".$firstdt."' AND '".$lastdt."' 
AND empid = '".$eid."'";
```

**How can I check if `logout_time` is NULL in this query?**

Comment: Can you define "is null"? No entry in that column of the database row?

Comment: Please, note that your code is probably vulnerable to an **SQL injection** attack! It's very dangerous to just _concatenate_ user input to build a query. **See an example [here](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really is not clear what you are exactly wishing to do. To test nullability use the `IS NULL` syntax : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null

The logout time can not both be '18:30:00' and null at the same time, so to hazard a guess, you are wanting

```
   WHERE ((logout_time > '16:30:00' AND logout_time < '18:30:00') OR logout_time) IS NULL) AND ...
```

Comment: sir, If employee goes form office without click on signoff button then   in database table logout field is show null. so I want to retrive that if logout field is also null

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT date FROM daily_entry_log_2011 WHERE logout_time > '16:30:00' AND  
logout_time < '18:30:00' OR logout_time IS NULL AND   date  BETWEEN '".$firstdt."' AND '".$lastdt."' 
 AND empid = '".$eid."'";
```